# Orange file import method for raw binaries

Tags: orange

I tried to add a  binary import method to
    class FileFormat(metaclass=FileFormatMeta)
in io.py, but gave up trying to adapt a copy of the CSV method since so much is specific to CSV issues and the comments are sparse...

Basically, given an Ncols x Mrows raw file of known type and meta data, one should be able to supply the shape, sample rate etc as defaults, and then one "only" needs to satisfy the parameters for Table.from_numpy(). It is the creation of Orange-specific objects that have me stuck, and mainly the domain object:

```
def data_table_from_bin(cls, data, headers=None):
    ...
    domain = Domain(attrs, clses, metas)

    table = Table.from_numpy(domain, X, Y, M, W)
    return table
```

Has anyone else tried this, or have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem exactly?

When you create **Domain** you have to specify each Feature eg:

```
from Orange.data import Domain, Table, ContinuousVariable, DiscreteVariable

d = Domain([ContinuousVariable.make('Attribute 1'), DiscreteVariable.make('Attribute 2')])
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.domain.html) to doc, regarding Domain (yes, it's not the best)